# symfony 4.4 + sonata deprecations like sonata.deprecated_text.twig.extension | sonata.twig.deprecated_template_extension

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata, symfony-sonata

I've installed **sonata + symfony 4.4** on new clean empty project.
Did everything according to https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/getting_started/installation.html
and executed the recipes , composer adviced me to apply.

But on pristine setup I'm having a few deprecations like:

> User Deprecated: The "sonata.twig.deprecated_template_extension"
> service is deprecated since sonata-project/twig-extensions 1.4.
>
> User Deprecated: The "sonata.deprecated_text.twig.extension" service
> is deprecated since sonata-project/admin-bundle 3.70. You should stop
> using it, as it will be removed in 4.0.
>
> The child node "legacy_twig_text_extension" at path
> "sonata_admin.options" is deprecated since sonata-project/admin-bundle
> 3.70 and will be removed in 4.0.

Is it ok? I don't have any legacy I've just set up compeltely new project?
Can I somehow avoid these deprecations or is it just an expected behavior and I have to get used to it?

[image]

Comment: afaik, it is just a notices that you shouldn't use it, if you suppose to update sonata to 3.0 version then.

Comment: Otherwise you should fix your code after update to fix code which uses deprecated items.

Comment: I've got used to treat every notice,warning or deprecation in my code as something that needs to be fixed as soon as possible. And just don't get why new code gives me so much deprecations...

Comment: Just a guess but it looks like 3.x itself has not been updated to remove the notices.  Unlike Symfony, the various Sonata components are not kept in sync.  You could open a github issue but I suspect you will just have to live with the notices until the bundle is updated.